# Efficiently fill a canvas with triangles wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to fill a canvas with non overlapping triangles of varying sizes and angles as efficiently as possible. I haven't been able to find any input on this subject online so i'm turning to you guys.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit] the question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Also please see **[ask]**.

Comment: In this case I would say: start with the Math first. *Would you know how to do it with paper, ruler and pen?* if you don't have the answer to that, then maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to start.

Comment: How do you define 'efficient' in this problem?

Comment: I'd set with a min and max edge length, and start with a random triangle. Then for every edge I'd create a new random point opposite the other point. Repeat this for the new edges, but check whether the new point is within the minimum distance to an existing point, and if so, use that instead.